# NLP Classifier - Python too many values to unpack

Tags: python, classification, nltk

Getting a valueerror when entering the classifier - the series in campaign_name is a string and tokenized_sents are several strings. What is happening?

```
df['campaign_name'] = str.lower(df.campaign_name)
df['tokenized_sents'] = df.campaign_name.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

X = df['tokenized_sents']
y = df['campaign_name']

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = tts(X, y, train_size=0.65, random_state=1)

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(xTrain,yTrain)

[ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for NLTK's Naive Bayes Classfier:

```
@classmethod
    def train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator=ELEProbDist):
        """
        :param labeled_featuresets: A list of classified featuresets,
            i.e., a list of tuples ``(featureset, label)``.
        """
```

You should be organizing the feature and label in a slight different way than you used to do in scikit-learn setup. Here, it's a list of tuples of featureset and labels rather than a matrix of features and a list of labels.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in two values xTrain and yTrain in `classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(xTrain,yTrain)`. You can only pass one to train on.

This might be what are looking for?

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(xTrain)

y_pred = classifier.classify(xTest)
```